# Use of undeclared identifier Amazons3client

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to follow the tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/articles/3002109349624271 for uploading images to an s3 bucket. This code throws an error saying use of undeclared identifier Amazons3client and use of undeclared identifier s3. I have searched and have tried adding multiple imports and none have worked.

```
#import "AmazonObjcStuff.h"
#import <AWSCore/AWSCore.h>
#import <AWSS3/AWSS3.h>



@implementation AmazonObjcStuff : NSObject


- (void) someMethod {
    NSLog(@"SomeMethod Ran");
    AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:"************" withSecretKey:"*****************************"] autorelease];
}

@end
```

Comment: given code is not full code to upload image to s3 bucket. if possible put whole code.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the tutorial you linked, it uses version 1 of the AWS SDK for iOS, and the code snippets are not compatible with the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS v2. You should take a look at [S3TransferManager-Sample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples) instead.